# T-SQL - Track occurrences over time

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, dimensional-modeling

I have some data which has `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo` dates associated with it. In simple terms:

```
MembershipId | ValidFromDate | ValidToDate
==========================================
0001         | 1997-01-01    | 2006-05-09
0002         | 1997-01-01    | 2017-05-12
0003         | 2005-06-02    | 2009-02-07
```

There is a non-clustered index on this table which includes the two dates as key values.

I also have a Date dimension table which covers every date from `1900` to `2999`.

I'm trying to figure out how I can select a range of dates from the Date dimension table (let's say `2016-01-01` to `2016-12-31`) and then identify, for each date, how many memberships were valid on that date.

The code below does the job but the performance isn't great and I was wondering whether anyone has any recommendations for a better way to go about this?

```
SELECT 
   d.DateKey
  ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Memberships AS m
    WHERE d.DateKey between m.ValidFromDateKey and m.ValidToDateKey
    ) AS MembershipCount

FROM       
   DIM.[Date] AS d

WHERE
   d.CalendarYear = 2016
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logic in your SQL is mostly correct, you have just implemented it poorly for how SQL likes to do things.  Starting with your `Dates` table as you have done already, rather than doing a sub-select for each row of data, change your logic to a `join` and you are there:

```
select d.DateKey
      ,count(m.MembershipID) as MembershipCount
from DIM.[Date] as d
    left join Memberships as m
        on(d.DateKey between m.ValidFromDateKey and m.ValidToDateKey)
where d.CalendarYear = 2016
group by d.DateKey
order by d.DateKey;
```

---

What you may want to be careful of is identifying which memberships are to be counted on each day.  For example, if your date is `2006-05-09` should MembershipID `0001` be included as it ends that day?

The question is essentially, are you counting the number of Memberships that were active at *any point* during the entire day, or just those that were active at a particular time, say the start or the end of the day?

Then repeat this thought process for your `ValidFromDate` values.

Comment: Fantastic! That works perfectly - When my query took >30 secs I aborted it but it now runs the full year in <1 second.

Thanks for the comment regarding the dates too. I just need to know whether the membership was valid at any point of each day and the ValidTo/From dates are inclusive, so your query is spot on.

Comment: Wow!  If this gives you the performance you need, then it is a good way to go.  There are other approaches when the non-equijoin takes too long.

Comment: @triplestones  SQL works using sets of data and is therefore very good at joining sets of data together.  Tables are just sets of data.  When you put another `select` statement within your main `select`, it is run for every row that is returned, rather than just the once and `join`ed together.  For further reading, look up "Set Based Thinking"

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Do you have examples of the other approaches?  Would be good to have a read through.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Was doing a similar thing to this earlier and remembered your mention of other methods here.  Could you provide a link to something that expands on these?

Comment: @iamdave . . . You should ask a question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff [Done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508697/aggregate-for-each-day-over-time-series-without-using-non-equijoin-logic)