# how to show every open item by weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello Everybody and sorry for my english if that's not correct.

I have a table with 3 column and many line >>

```
Item ID|   Opening_date | Closed_date
```

THe request I need is: every ongoing Item grouped by week during the year.
The answer shoulk look like

```
week 1     45 ongoing item
week 2     32 ongoing item
...  
Week 37    64 ongoing item
```

So I tried 'with cte as' but i can't get what I want

Thank you for your help
Best Regards 
Antoine

Edit with sample:

```
414   |  2018-01-01  |  2018-05-01
416   |  2018-01-08  |  2018-05-01
417   |  2018-01-08  |  2018-04-01
```

to determine the week I use select datepart(ww, date  )
ongoing item is item open and not closed.
With those value , the result i want is

```
1   |  1  
2   |  3  
3   |  3  
...
27  |  3
28  |  2
```

Comment: Could you please share what you have tried already?

Comment: please post more sample data with the corresponding expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by referencing a list of the appropriate weeks that cover your dataset.  This is most easily achieved through use of a dates table, though if unavailable it is trivial to generate one via `cte`:

```
declare @t table(id int, OpeningDate date, ClosingDate date);
insert into @t values
 (414,  '20180101',  '20180501')
,(416,  '20180108',  '20180501')
,(417,  '20180108',  '20180401')
;

declare @StartWeek date = (select dateadd(week,datediff(week,0,min(OpeningDate)),0) from @t);
declare @EndWeek date = (select dateadd(week,datediff(week,0,max(ClosingDate)),0) from @t);

with n(n) as (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1)
    ,d(d) as (select top(datediff(week,@StartWeek,@EndWeek)+1) dateadd(week,row_number() over (order by (select null))-1,@StartWeek) from n n1,n n2,n n3,n n4,n n5)
select d.d as WeekStart
    ,count(t.id) as OpenItems
from d
    left join @t as t
        on t.OpeningDate <= d.d
            and (t.ClosingDate > d.d
                 or t.ClosingDate is null
                 )
group by d.d
order by d.d;
```

Output:

```
+---------------------+-----------+
|      WeekStart      | OpenItems |
+---------------------+-----------+
| 01.01.2018 00:00:00 |         1 |
| 08.01.2018 00:00:00 |         3 |
| 15.01.2018 00:00:00 |         3 |
| 22.01.2018 00:00:00 |         3 |
| 29.01.2018 00:00:00 |         3 |
| 05.02.2018 00:00:00 |         3 |
| 12.02.2018 00:00:00 |         3 |
| 19.02.2018 00:00:00 |         3 |
| 26.02.2018 00:00:00 |         3 |
| 05.03.2018 00:00:00 |         3 |
| 12.03.2018 00:00:00 |         3 |
| 19.03.2018 00:00:00 |         3 |
| 26.03.2018 00:00:00 |         3 |
| 02.04.2018 00:00:00 |         2 |
| 09.04.2018 00:00:00 |         2 |
| 16.04.2018 00:00:00 |         2 |
| 23.04.2018 00:00:00 |         2 |
| 30.04.2018 00:00:00 |         2 |
+---------------------+-----------+
```

---

If your dataset is too large for this to perform fast enough, there are other slightly more complex design patterns that you can use to make the query more efficient.  You can see a good discussion of the various options here: [Aggregate for each day over time series, without using non-equijoin logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508697/aggregate-for-each-day-over-time-series-without-using-non-equijoin-logic)

Comment: that looks good to me, let me understand and adapt it and i will close the subject , Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

do you need to consider the `Closed_date` against the week ending date ?

```
SELECT DATEPART(week, [DATE]) as Week,
       SUM (CASE WHEN Closed_date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as OnGoingItem
FROM   yourtable
GROUP BY DATEPART(week, [DATE])
```

Comment: sorry maybe i'm not clear enough, but with your request i only get the week where I open item that is still open . for example on february(so probably week 5,6,7,8) i will see 3 item every week

Answer (score 0):

I would expand the data by week and then aggregation:

```
with cte as (
      select opening_date, closed_date, opening_date as dte
      from yourtable
      union all
      select opening_date, closed_date, dateadd(week, 1, opening_date)
      from cte
      where dte < closed_date
     )
select datepart(week, dte), count(*)
from cte
where dte >= '2018-01-01' and dte < '2019-01-01'
group by datepart(week, dte)
order by min(dte)
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: THis one looked easier but i have an error: Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.